# How to assert that download popup is active? selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to verify that download link is correct and when you click it that document is created for downloading.

so how can I assert that when test clicks link, after some time there is a download popup (sometimes there is no popup and I need test to fail then)

Comment: what does 'download popup' mean? You mean standard popup asking what you want to do (open or save file)? Popups like that depends on browser settings...

Comment: @kotoj yes, this popup. I do not need to interact with it, but I just need to verify that it was shown, is there some way to do that??

Comment: I think there is no way using only Selenium. My way of handling download cases is: 1. create browser profile with autodownload, 2. click download button (file download automatically), 3. check if file is downloaded 4. delete downloaded file